# multiple route point for multiple sightseeing place google map api

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, dictionary

I have multiple sightseeing place map with multiple marker. I want to draw route path in between each marker. In functions.php (wordpress) i have an array. You will find that array in `$bicycleGeoCode` then find `'bicycles' => array(array)`.

See screenshot here of my multiple marker

[image]

```
function chatbot_cycle_pass_enqueue_scripts(){
    global $cmb_booking, $cmb_review, $cmb_store, $cmb_user, $contentLang;

    //load full version or minified version of javascript
    //$prefix = WP_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    $prefix = NULL;

    // Google Fonts
    //wp_enqueue_style( 'natosans', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');
    // Theme CSS files
    $GoogleMapsSRC = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js";
    //key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
    //http_build_query()
    $GoogleMapsQuery = array();
    $GoogleMepsApi = GetAdminOptions("google_maps_api");
    if($GoogleMepsApi != FALSE)
        $GoogleMapsQuery["key"] = $GoogleMepsApi;
        $GoogleMapsQuery["libraries"] = "geometry";
        $GoogleMapsQuery["language"] = $contentLang;
        $GoogleMapsQuery = http_build_query(apply_filters("googlemapsapi", $GoogleMapsQuery));
        $GoogleMapsSRC .= (!empty($GoogleMapsQuery))? "?".$GoogleMapsQuery : "";
        wp_register_script("GoogleMaps2", $GoogleMapsSRC, false, THEME_VERSION );

        wp_register_script( 'GoogleMapsInfoWindow2', TemplateURL . "/cycle_assets/infobox{$prefix}.js", array( "GoogleMaps2" ) , THEME_VERSION, true );

        wp_register_script( 'BicycleGeoCodeAPI2', TemplateURL . "/js/chatbot_cycle_pass_geocode.js", array( "GoogleMaps2", 'GoogleMapsInfoWindow2', 'jquery') , THEME_VERSION, true );

        $bicycleGeoCode = apply_filters("bicycle_geocode_ajax_object", array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'home_url' => site_url(),
            'center' => array( "latitude" => 34.695094, "longitude" => 135.193806),
            'marker_bicycle' => TemplateURL . "/cycle_assets/bicycle_marker.png",
            'marker_user' => TemplateURL . "/img/marker-user.png",
            'close_btn' => TemplateURL . "/cycle_assets/btn_close.gif",
            'tip' => TemplateURL . "/cycle_assets/tipbox.png",
            'GeoCodelocationDataAlert' => __("Please check your location sharing settings.", 'tebura'),
            'locationNotSupported' => __("Your Browser/Device doesn't support Geo Location API.",'tebura'),
            'locationDataAlert' => __("Please Check Your Location Sharing Settings.", 'tebura'),
            'locationDataTimeOutAlert' => __("Request Timeout during processing your location data.<br>Please Reload Your Browser",'tebura'),
            'locationDataPositionUnavailableAlert' => __("Your Position is Unavailable.<br>Please Activate Your GPS And Location Services And Reload The Page.",'tebura'),
            'locationDataPermissionDeniedAlert' => __("Your Location Sharing Settings Is Blocked.<br>Please Change Your Location Sharing Settings And Reload The Page.",'tebura'),
            'locationDataUnknownErrorAlert' => __("An Unknown Error Occurred.<br>Please Try Again After Sometime.", 'tebura'),
            'bookingButtonText' => __("Click here to book now.", 'tebura'),
            'storeDistanceTimeText' => __("Nearest baggage claim distance is {0} and it would take approximate {1} to get there.", 'tebura'),
            'bicycles' => array(
                array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port1.jpg',
                    'title' => 'Shibuya City Test',
                    'Address' => 'Japan, 〒151-0063 Tōkyō-to, Shibuya City, Tomigaya, 1-chōme−3−８ 第２２ＳＹビル',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '15 Available',
                    'latitude' => '35.669187',
                    'longitude' => '139.689099'
                ),
                array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port1.jpg',
                    'title' => '三宮駅前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区三宮町1丁目10',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '15 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.693094',
                    'longitude' => '135.193806'
                ),
                array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port2.jpg',
                    'title' => '元町駅前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区元町高架通',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '15 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.689873',
                    'longitude' => '135.188265'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port3.jpg',
                    'title' => 'ハーバーランド',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区東川崎町1丁目8',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '15 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.680873',
                    'longitude' => '135.183115'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port4.jpg',
                    'title' => '北野工房のまち',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区中山手通3丁目17',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '15 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.695887',
                    'longitude' => '135.187096'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port5.jpg',
                    'title' => '三宮アーバンエースビル前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区小野柄通4丁目1',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '14 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.694899',
                    'longitude' => '135.199250'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port6.jpg',
                    'title' => 'JR新神戸駅前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区加納町1丁目3',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '18 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.706077',
                    'longitude' => '135.195554'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port7.jpg',
                    'title' => '神戸市役所前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区加納町6-5-1',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '14 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.689935',
                    'longitude' => '135.195788'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port8.jpg',
                    'title' => '北野町中公園',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区北野町3丁目10',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '5 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.701062',
                    'longitude' => '135.189503'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port9.jpg',
                    'title' => 'メリケンパーク',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区波止場町2',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '5 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.681460',
                    'longitude' => '135.187654'
                ), array(
                    'ImgURL' => TemplateURL . '/cycle_assets/cycles/img_port10.jpg',
                    'title' => '兵庫県立美術館前',
                    'Address' => '神戸市中央区脇浜海岸通1丁目1−1',
                    'Time' => '24時間',
                    'Max' => '5 Available',
                    'latitude' => '34.699897',
                    'longitude' => '135.218344'
                )
            ),
        ));
        wp_enqueue_script( "GoogleMaps2" );
        if ( is_page_template( 'chatbot_cycle_pass.php' ) )
            wp_localize_script( 'BicycleGeoCodeAPI2', 'bicycleGeoCode', $bicycleGeoCode );
            if ( is_page_template( 'chatbot_cycle_pass.php' ) ){
                wp_enqueue_script( 'GoogleMapsInfoWindow2' );
                wp_enqueue_script( 'BicycleGeoCodeAPI2' );
            }
            //      debug_dump(get_page_template_slug());
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chatbot_cycle_pass_enqueue_scripts', 11);
```